# Yeoman SPFx issue with installing @microsoft/sharepoint generator

Tags: java, sharepoint, yeoman, spfx, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to learn how to use SPFx, however I'm falling down at the first step when it comes to running `yo @microsoft/sharepoint`.

I get the following error when running `yo @microsoft/sharepoint`:

```
Error @microsoft/sharepoint

You don't seem to have a generator with the name “@microsoft/sharepoint” installed.
But help is on the way:

You can see available generators via npm search yeoman-generator or via http://yeoman.io/generators/.
Install them with npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint.

To see all your installed generators run yo --generators. Adding the --help option will also show subgenerators.

If yo cannot find the generator, run yo doctor to troubleshoot your system.
```

I have tried running `npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint -g` however this does not resolve the above error. It's also worth noting that I get a bunch of errors when running the install generator command:

```
    npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.13.0',
    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=12.13.0 <13.0.0 || >=14.15.0 <15.0.0' },
    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.1.0' }
    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
    npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces@1.13.0',
    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=12.13.0 <13.0.0 || >=14.15.0 <15.0.0' },
    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.1.0' }
    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
    npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
    npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies
    .
    npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies
    .
    npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams
     API instead.
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.1.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain
     circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain
     circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain
     circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain
     circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain
     circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
    npm WARN deprecated @opentelemetry/types@0.2.0: Package renamed to @opentelemetry/api, see https://github.com/open-telem
    etry/opentelemetry-js
    npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to     v2.x.x.
    npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please
     upgrade asap.
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path     C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint\node_modules\node-sas
    s
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
    npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe     C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\gene
rator-sharepoint\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= -    -libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldfl
    ags= --libsass_library=
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli       'C:\\Users\\%username%\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@microsoft\\generator-    sharepoint\\n
    ode_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
    npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
    npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError     (C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsof
t\generator-sharepoint\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F     (C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sha
    repoint\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E     (C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sha
    repoint\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at     C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharep
        oint\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at     C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharep
    oint\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at     C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharep
    oint\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError     (C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsof
    t\generator-sharepoint\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F         (C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sha
    repoint\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E     (C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sha
    repoint\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at     C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharep
    oint\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at     C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharep
    oint\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at     C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharep
    oint\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Program Files\Python310\python.EXE
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Python310\python.EXE     -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % s
    ys.version_info[:3];
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you     mean print(...)?
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit     (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"     "C:\\Users\\%username%\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modu
    les\\@microsoft\\generator-sharepoint\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"     "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext="
    "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd     C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-    sharepoint\node_modules\
    node-sass
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-12T03_25_38_209Z-debug.log
```

Could anyone please help troubleshoot this with me? I'm not sure what is causing the issues with the @microsoft/sharepoint generator install, but something is seemingly preventing it from installing properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the issue is that I was using the latest version of Node.js (v16.13.0) when I needed to be using a supported version (v14.15.0)

Comment: As you have solved the issue, you can mark the answer to cloase this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Node v14 is the key here. Atleast working for me by downloading the node v14.18.

Answer (score 0):

1.[Install the latest version of Node.js LTS v14](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment#install-nodejs).

2.install the latest version of npm: npm i -g npm@next

3.run the following in your cmd window or commander window:

```
npm uninstall -g chalk
npm uninstall -g loadash
npm uninstall -g tar-fs
npm uninstall -g update-notifier
npm uninstall -g yeoman-generator
npm uninstall -g yosay
npm uninstall -g yo
npm uninstall -g gulp
npm uninstall -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
npm install -g chalk
npm install -g loadash
npm install -g tar-fs
npm install -g update-notifier
npm install -g yeoman-generator
npm install -g yosay
npm install -g yo
npm install -g gulp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try different versions of Node v14. Mine did not work for node 14.17 but worked for v14.19